# Fetching data using createSQLQuery in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

> Blockquote

I am using `createSQLQuery()` in hibernate. I store values in `List<Student> studentList`, but am unable to get values from list using `studentList.get(i).getStudentID();` It's throwing a `NullPointerException`. However, when I print the size of list using `studentList.size()`, it's indicating list size is eight.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
```

import java.util.Date;

public class EfwStageLog implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer stage_log_id;
private Date moment;
private Date end_time;
private String exec_status;
private int stage_id;



public Integer getStage_log_id() {
    return stage_log_id;
}
public void setStage_log_id(Integer stage_log_id) {
    this.stage_log_id = stage_log_id;
}
public Date getMoment() {
    return moment;
}
public void setMoment(Date moment) {
    this.moment = moment;
}
public Date getEnd_time() {
    return end_time;
}
public void setEnd_time(Date end_time) {
    this.end_time = end_time;
}
public String getExec_status() {
    return exec_status;
}
public void setExec_status(String exec_status) {
    this.exec_status = exec_status;
}
public int getStage_id() {
    return stage_id;
}
public void setStage_id(int stage_id) {
    this.stage_id = stage_id;
}
```

}

> StageExecution.java

```
public class StageExecution  extends ActionSupport{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
List<EfwStageLog> stagelogList;
EfwStageLog efwstagelog;
EfwStageExecutionManager stageexecutionmnager;
public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}
public StageExecution()
{
    stageexecutionmnager = new EfwStageExecutionManager();
}
public String AverageStageWiseExecution()
{
    System.out.println("I m in avgSWE+++++++++++++++++++++");
    efwstagelog = new EfwStageLog();
    stagelogList = stageexecutionmnager.getAverageStageExecutionDetail(stagelogList);
    System.out.println("stagelogList.size============"+stagelogList.size());
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

> EfwStageExecutionManager.java

```
public class EfwStageExecutionManager {
List <EfwStageLog> stageLogList;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<EfwStageLog> getAverageStageExecutionDetail(List<EfwStageLog> efwstageLog)
{
    System.out.println("I am in getLastStageExecutionDetail=========");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    efwstageLog =session.createSQLQuery("select stage_id,(def/c) as ax from ((select stage_id,sum(end_time-moment) as def, COUNT(*) c,(sum(end_time-moment)/COUNT(*)) as man FROM efw_db.efw_stage_logs GROUP BY stage_id HAVING c > 1) as ab)").list();
   efwstageLog.get(0).getStage_id();
   }
   }
```

I am getting error at point" efwstageLog.get(0).getStage_id();"

> HTTP Status 500 - [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.helical.efw.model.EfwStageLog

Comment: read about lazy initialization.

Comment: Post some code to let us see what is wrong.

Comment: maybe it's nothing to do with the data returned from hibernate. show the code from the line that's exploding.

Comment: Debug into it and see what is actually being returned.